# Difference between calling method with self and with class name?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class A:

    def __init__(self, text):
        self.printStats()
        A.printStats(text)

    def printStats(self):
        print(self)

a = A("Hello")
```

This prints:

```
<A object at 0x7f47e2f08ac8>
Hello
```

Why is this (`A.printStats(text)`) possible? I understand what is happening (`self` references `text`), but I don't understand why.

Comment: `self.instance_method()` is equivalent to `Class.instance_method(self)`. If your method doesn't actually use any instance state (e.g. access attributes on `self`) you can pass in anything.

Comment: You're passing `text` (which is "Hello" in your example) as the `self` argument to `printStats`, which is really not what you should do. But that's why you see "Hello" printed.

Comment: Thanks for a first question with good spelling and grammar! You have no idea how many low quality first posts there are...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an instance of the class:

```
a = A('some text')
```

The `self` argument becomes permanently bound to `a`, this is the magic behind classes. If you try `a.printStats('something')` this will raise an error as `self` argument is already occupied by `a`. You can recover the original function that has unbound self with `a.printFunction.__func__`. Try `a.printFunction.__func__('this will be self argument')`

However, when you don't create an instance there is nothing to bind `self` to so `self` is still available for use. In such case you can treat `A` as a simple dictionary holding functions.

```
A = {'__init__': someInitFunction,
     'printStats': printStatsFunction}
```

You have to remember that the name `self` is arbitrary and you can use any word instead, even `not_self`.

Answer (score 5):

```
A.printStats(text)
```

does NOT call `printStats` with an instance of `A`. It calls it with a string - no `self` is passed.

```
def printStats(self):
    # <--- here, "self" if the string "Hello", not an instance of A.
    print(self)
```

---

`A.printStats(self)` is equivalent to `self.printStats`. Likewise if you have a function `printStatsWithPrefix`;

```
class A:
    def printStatsWithPrefix(self, prefix):
        ...  # function body goes here
```

you'd have to do `A.printStatsWithPrefix(self, prefix)`.

---

**A note on style:** By Python convention (PEP 8), you should use `lowercase_with_underscores` for function names.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. What do you mean by "it calls it with a string"? Edit: Nevermind, got it.

Comment: @d9h "calling" means to execute a function with the given parameters. You executed the function, and instead of using `self` as an instance of `A`, you used a string.

Answer (score 1):

Your code would fail in Python 2 as calling a method via the class requires that the first argument of the class is actually an instance of the class.

In Python 3, the implementation is less stricter as the first argument is only expected to implement the required interface pertaining to an instance of the class; no check on whether the parameter is an instance is performed. And since you're not actually accessing any instance method/variable inside `printStats` via `self` this works and it simply prints the passed string `'hello'`.