# Calling a static method with self vs. class name

Tags: python, static-methods

Calling Python static methods using the class name is more common, but can be a real eye sore for long class names. Sometimes I use `self` within the same class to call the static methods, because I find it looks cleaner.

```py
class ASomewhatLongButDescriptiveClassName:

   def __init__(self):
      # This works, but it's an eyesore
      ASomewhatLongButDescriptiveClassName.do_something_static()

      # This works too and looks cleaner.
      self.do_something_static()

   @staticmethod
   def do_something_static():
      print('Static method called.')
```

My understanding is that calling a static method with `self` gets interpreted as `ClassName.static_method(self)`, where `self` would be ignored by the static method.
**(EDIT: The above statement is only true for instance methods, not static methods)**

Are there any concrete reasons why I should not use `self` to call static methods within the same class?

> FWIW This is a sister question to [Difference between calling method with self and with class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41552349/difference-between-calling-method-with-self-and-with-class-name), which deals with non-static methods.

Comment: ``"I understand that calling a static method with self is the same as ClassName.static_method(self) [...]"`` no it's not the same. That's only true for **instance** methods. Though you are using it correctly in your example, so I guess you are just misquoting a comment from the other linked SO question.

Comment: If you want to make use of a static method in the context of an instance method (e.g. `__init__` in your example, then by all means use `self`. Of course, if you want to access the method from outside an instance, `self` will have no meaning, so you'll have to use the full class name.

Comment: Lets clarify what "outside an instance" means. If you have created `foo = ASomewhatLongButDescriptiveClassName()`, you _should_ access the static method via `foo.do_something_static()`.

Comment: I would advise *just stop using `staticmethod` and just use a regular, module-level function*.

Comment: I can only agree with @juanpa.arrivillaga - from the mistakes in the earlier question and from the follow-up, we have to question why you're even trying to use static methods?

Comment: @Grismar When a method doesn't rely on `self`, the IDE (e.g. PyCharm) recommends making it static, so I do that to remove the warning. I assume the rational is to avoid the unused `self` parameter as a best practice.

Comment: @DV82XL a better solution is probably to just *not to make it a method at all* and just make it a regular function, outside the class

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You make a few statements that aren't entirely correct:

> Calling Python static methods using the class name is more common

It's not more common, it's the only way to do so from outside the class. i.e.:

```
class MyClass:
    @staticmethod
    def a_method():
        pass


MyClass.a_method()
```

In this example, `self.a_method()` would not work, as `self` would not refer to an instance of `MyClass`.

> calling a static method with self is the same as ClassName.static_method(self), where self would be ignored by the static method

That's not actually the case, for example:

```
class MyClass:
    @staticmethod
    def a_method():
        pass

    def another_method(self):
        # this is fine
        self.a_method()
        # this causes an error, as .a_method expects no arguments
        MyClass.a_method(self)
```

`self` simply refers to the instance of the class that called an instance method (which has the `self` argument, which doesn't even have to be called `self` - it's just whatever the first parameter is called, `self` is the convention.

You can call static methods on `self`, because self is an instance of the class that has the static method, and thus has the method. You can also call static methods on classes directly, because a static method doesn't require an object instance as a first argument - which is the point of the static method.

You're fine using `self.a_method()` where you like, just keep in mind that `self` will refer to an object of the class the object was instanced as, not the specific class you mention.

For example:

```
class ClassA:
    @staticmethod
    def a_method():
        print('a')

    def another_method(self):
        # prints whatever a_method for the class of self prints
        self.a_method()
        # always prints 'a', as a_method for ClassA prints 'a'
        ClassA.a_method()


class ClassB(ClassA):
    @staticmethod
    def a_method():
        print('b')


a = ClassA()
a.another_method()
b = ClassB()
b.another_method()
```

The output:

```
a
a
b
a
```

So, you see, there is a difference between calling from `self.` and from `Class.`

Comment: If you want to avoid repeating the class name in the call, an alternative to the `ClassA.a_method()` call inside `another_method()` is `__class__.a_method()`. This also always prints 'a', as `a_method` for `ClassA` prints 'a', and `__class__` at this location _is_ `ClassA`.

Answer (score -1):

Here are two examples of number formatting that use static functions:
First, a simple thousands separator formatting method

```py
class Car:

    def __init__(self, color: str, mileage: int):
        self.color: str = color
        self.mileage: int = mileage

    @staticmethod
    def format_with_comma_separator(amount: float) -> str:
        return f"{amount:,}"

    def __str__(self):
        # notice that mileage is printed with commas for thousands separation
        return f'The {self.color} car has {Car.format_with_comma_separator(self.mileage)} miles.'
```

Second example formats a floating point number as US-EN currency:

```py
import locale

class Truck:

    def __init__(self, color: str, mileage: int, cost: float):
        self.color: str = color
        self.mileage: int = mileage
        self.cost: float = cost

    @staticmethod
    def format_currency(amount: float) -> str:
        # set locale to US
        locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')
        # format currency value
        return locale.currency(amount, grouping=True)

    def __str__(self):
        # notice that mileage is printed with commas for thousands separation and cost is formatted as currency (US)
        return f'The {self.color} truck has {self.mileage:,} miles and costs {Truck.format_currency(self.cost)}.'
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).